# After copying the not-matching parent records from one database to another; how would you map it with the existing child records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, subquery

For Example:

You have 2 database: Development and Production and having identical tables.

Now, suppose you have tables `ProductionDb`

```
1. Products
2. ProductTypes

Products

Id   Name   Type_ID
1    A      1
2.   B      2
3.   C      3

ProductTypes

Id  TypeName
1    Type-A
2    Type-B
3.   Type-C
```

Now, you transfer all this data into the Development db using a query

```
Insert into DevelopmentDb.dbo.Products
Select Name, Type_ID from ProductionDb.dbo.Products
```

This make the data in the table Products of `DevelopmentDb` identical to the Products table of `ProductionDb's`.

Consider we assumed that `ProductTypes` table would always remain the same in both databases hence the reference keys in Products table to `ProductTypes` would remain relevant.

But

Now, consider that the Product Type doesn't have the same info e.g.

In `DevelopmentDb` the `ProductTypes` have these rows.

ProductTypes

```
Id  TypeName
1    Type-A
3    Type-B
5.   Type-C
6.   Type-B
```

Notice? The change of IDs.

Now, the issue is that Products that have been copied from `Product` into `Development` references the `ProductTypes` might not be exactly the same.

Now, to solve this I might do this:

Before INSERTING the data into the Products I will sync and update the `ProductTypes` i.e.

```
INSERT INTO DevelopmentDb.dbo.ProductTypes
Select TypeName from ProductionDb.dbo.ProductTypes ppt
Where NOT EXISTS (Select TypeName from DevelopmentDb.dbo.ProductTypes where TypeName = ppt.TypeName)
```

would get the new data.

But still while inserting the data from `ProductionDb` into the `DevelopmentDB's` Products table. How would you map the copied data to the newly created `ProductTypes` since the Type_ID in the products being copied are referencing to the `ProductTypes` in the `ProductionDb` where Ids are/might be different then the one newly created in the `ProductTypes` after synning.

How to solve this issue?

Note: the only option is to copy data using the queries and not replication.

Comment: You can map type Ids by TypeName. Alternatively  you can use identity insert to copy exactly id from Production.

Comment: [set identity_insert on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: @Serg that's a very good idea but problem is what if the IDs exists already in the target table e.g. I am copying 3,4,7,8 from source but 3,8 already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Use Merge operation and its output to collect a mapping table.

```
declare @MappingIds (
    OldTypeId  int  primary key, 
    NewTypeId  int  unique
);

merge into DevelopmentDb.dbo.ProductTypes as target
    using 
    (
        select Id, TypeName from ProductionDb.dbo.ProductTypes
    ) 
    as source on source.TypeName = target.TypeName 

when matched then
    update set                
        TypeName = source.TypeName          

when not matched by target then                                                         
    insert ( TypeName )
    values ( source.TypeName)

output source.Id, inserted.Id        
into @MappingIds (OldTypeId, NewTypeId);


merge into DevelopmentDb.dbo.Products as target
    using 
    (
        select 
             p.Id
             p.Name 
             Type_ID = ids.NewTypeId
        from 
            ProductionDb.dbo.Products p
            inner join @MappingIds ids on ids.OldTypeId = p.Type_ID
    ) 
    as source on source.Id = target.Id

when matched then
    update set                
        Name = source.Name,
        Type_ID = Type_ID 

when not matched by target then                                                         
    insert ( Name,   Type_ID )
    values ( source.Name, source.Type_ID);
```

Comment: hi, vadim. thanks man. I will give it a try tomorrow and let you know.